# Drawable VS Bitmap in a specific case

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm developing a music Player, and since i have started I've a question: Should i use Drawable or Bitmap?
Considered that:

I have to load many images, one for every song (The image is loaded only when it is the turn of that song).

The image loaded has to be visualized on the Widget and Notification too.

The same image is displayed on more activities.

The image loading has to be as fast as possible.

The memory usage have to be as low as possible, even after have loaded several images.

I was thinking to temporarly save images of actual playlist, so I don't have to reload it every time is played the same song.

I am using Glide library to have better performance in this moment, and I am working with bitmap. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawable is just a  wrapper for things that can be drown (colors, vector images, layer-lists, selectors and bitmaps).

Whereas bitmaps are actually representation of images in Android.
So, your question is invalid, we can not equate bitmap and Drawable.

Comment: I asked beacuse on some question i saw that some one prefer Drawable instead of Bitmap

Comment: @SluggedGerm2 ok, so, when you set BITMAP to imageview it creates a BITMAP_DRAWABLE which is sublclass of DRAWABLE. So, eventually, you set DRAWABLE. And because of it, your question is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Both graphics objects works almost everywhere.

If you loading from file system (downloads) you need to load Bitmaps to create BitmapDrawables so you may apply bitmap directly in this case.

If you are using from the res folder you can load as Drawables.